# add column to DF when two variables are matched with second DF

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, lookup

I am looking to add another column to `DF1` below which returns the population of the relevant country for the year of the observation. I.e when country **and** year match with `DF2`, population is added to a column in `DF2`. I have used `merge` for matching only one variable before, is there a method to complete for two variables?

DF1:

```
eventid    |iyear | imonth| iday | CountryTxt
1.97000e+1 |1970  |      7|    2 |  Albania
1.97000e+11|  1970|      0|    0 |  United Kingdom
1.97001e+11|  1984|      1|    0 |  Somalia
1.97001e+11|  1990|      1|    0 |  France
1.97001e+11|  1991|      1|    0 |  New Zealand
```

DF2:

```
Country.Name|Code|Year|Population
Aruba       |ABW |1960| 123
Afganistan  |AFG |1970| 456
Albania     |ALB |1970| 1000
France      |FRA |1990| 5000
```

Comment: what is the relationship of this question to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603623/r-add-new-column-in-df-when-two-variables-match-with-second-df .... ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well within the capabilities of `merge()`: note all of the emphasized words in the quote from `?merge`, which are plural, i.e. the function can work on multiple matching columns ...

> by, by.x, by.y: specifications of the **columns** used for merging.  See
> ‘Details’.
>
> ...
>
> By default the data frames are merged on the **columns** with **names**
> they both have, but separate specifications of the **columns** can be
> given by ‘by.x’ and ‘by.y’.  The rows in the two data frames that
> match on the specified **columns** are extracted

```r
merge(df1,df2,
      by.x=c("iyear","CountryTxt"),
      by.y=c("Year","Country.Name"))
```

```
  iyear CountryTxt     eventid imonth iday Code Population
1  1970    Albania 1.97000e+01      7    2  ALB       1000
2  1990     France 1.97001e+11      1    0  FRA       5000
```

### data setup

```r
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE,sep="|",  strip.white=TRUE, text="
eventid    |iyear | imonth| iday | CountryTxt
1.97000e+1 |1970  |      7|    2 |  Albania
1.97000e+11|  1970|      0|    0 |  United Kingdom
1.97001e+11|  1984|      1|    0 |  Somalia
1.97001e+11|  1990|      1|    0 |  France
1.97001e+11|  1991|      1|    0 |  New Zealand
")

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE,sep="|",  strip.white=TRUE, text="
Country.Name|Code|Year|Population
Aruba       |ABW |1960| 123
Afganistan  |AFG |1970| 456
Albania     |ALB |1970| 1000
France      |FRA |1990| 5000
")
```